# How to Rewrite an onclick() Function in my Javascript to Call a Function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I created a map using Leaflet with clusters.  I wanted to add a popup when you click the cluster and it will show a popup list of names of the markers inside the cluster.  I found a code and it does exactly what I’m looking for:  a list popup showing the names of the markers inside the cluster and when you click on the different names on the popup list the related marker popup appears.  But when I added the code to my project, I get the error, “reference error onclick is not defined” and the function won't run.  I research this error and I found it’s not good practice to use the onclick function in my javascript/HTML in the way the code is written.  My question is, how do I rewrite the script to work the way the example I’m using.  Here’s a link to the example I’m using to show what I’m trying to accomplish (and this example works when I download it and run it…no error) - http://www.digital-geography.com/working-with-clusters-in-leaflet-increasing-useability/.  And I also included my script.  Any help on how to make this work will greatly be appreciated.  Or, I’m open to achieve this in a different way.  Thanks in advance!

```
function openPopUp(id, clusterId){
map.closePopup(); //which will close all popups
map.eachLayer(function(layer){     //iterate over map layer
if (layer._leaflet_id == clusterId){         // if layer is markerCluster
layer.spiderfy(); //spiederfies our cluster
     }
});
map.eachLayer(function(layer){//iterate over map rather than clusters
if (layer._leaflet_id == id){// if layer is marker
layer.openPopup();
     }
});

markers.on('clusterclick', function(a){
if(a.layer._zoom == 6){
var myText = '<ul>';
for (feat in a.layer._markers){
myText += '<li><u onclick="openPopUp"(' + a.layer._markers[feat]._leaflet_id + ',' + a.layer._leaflet_id + ')>' + a.layer._markers[feat].feature.properties['cityName2'] + ',' + a.layer._markers[feat].feature.properties['cityName2'] + '</u></li>';
        }
myText += '</u>';
var popup = L.popup().setLatLng([a.layer._cLatLng.lat,a.layer._cLatLng.lng]).setContent(myText).openOn(map);

    }
})
```

Comment: `"reference error onclick is not defined"` Is that really the exact error text? Sounds very strange

Comment: Sorry, it say "ReferenceError: openPopUp is not defined[Learn More]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.setContent` *can* accept an `HTMLElement` rather than just an HTML string, all you need to do is pass in an element with the listener attached, instead of the HTML string - construct the elements explicitly with `createElement`, and use `addEventListener` on the element you want to attach the listener to:

```
markers.on('clusterclick', function(a) {
  if (a.layer._zoom !== 6) return;
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');
  a.layer._markers.forEach(({ _leaflet_id, feature }) => {
    const { cityName2 } = feature.properties;
    const li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    const u = li.appendChild(document.createElement('u'));
    u.addEventListener('click', () => openPopUp(_leaflet_id, a.layer._leaflet_id));
    u.textContent = cityName2 + ',' + cityName2;
  });
  const popup = L
    .popup()
    .setLatLng([a.layer._cLatLng.lat, a.layer._cLatLng.lng])
    .setContent(ul)
    .openOn(map);
})
```

Comment: Got a quick question, I thought I could fix it but I can't figure it out.  When the list pop up it's showing undefined for the information that goes in that are (cityName2).  Any ideas?  Everything else work perfect.

Comment: Sorry, not undefined.  It say, [object Object],.  It reading in the data from a csv file.

Comment: Oops, looks like you have to go through the `properties` sub-object as well. `const { cityName2 } = feature.properties;`, see edit

Comment: I wanted to let you know your fix worked!  I'm sorry I missed adding that comment letting you know. Thanks again for your help!